# Writing to serial port in Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, serial-port

I am trying to write a native program (in C, using NDK) that reads and writes data to the serial port in Android. However, I am not sure which serial port to use. There are so many of them under /dev (tty0 to tty63). Please let me know which port I need to use. I am able to view the system logs using putty (connected to a com port in my PC), but not the output from my program.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found that android has a serialport-api and the sample app provided in the project site helped me find out the port number of my android device.

The links are [this](http://www.magora-systems.com/blog/serial-port-rs232-and-android/) and [this](http://code.google.com/p/android-serialport-api/).